# how is this doc inside browser achieved?

Tags: flash

http://www.docstoc.com/docs/356624/Code-Reuse-in-Object-Oriented-Software-Development

Answer (score 1):

Check out Scribd (http://www.scribd.com) if you're interested in quickly having something like this on your site.

Answer (score 1):

More specifically it looks to be [Adobe FlashPaper](http://www.adobe.com/products/flashpaper/), a technology built on Flash that gives you a kind of embeddable PDF, but without using iframes. Apart from exact layout capabilities, the major advantage is printing.

Answer (score 0):

With the [Adobe Flash Player](http://www.adobe.com/software/flash/about/).